# :id => 'current' in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I came across a [demo](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/blob/master/episode-141/store/config/routes.rb) with the following line:

```
 map.current_cart 'cart', :controller => 'carts', :action => 'show', :id => 'current'
```

Does setting the `id` to `'current'` call the function `current_cart` by some magic?

application_controller.rb:

```
 def current_cart
  session[:cart_id] ||= Cart.create!.id
  @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
 end
```

Comment: I think you should use before_filter here to call current_user or call this method directly

Comment: @ka8725 - sorry, I'm not sure what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [carts_controller](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/blob/master/episode-141/store/app/controllers/carts_controller.rb). Method `current_cart` calls from action `show`. So there is not any magic: it is just calling method from action and it do the next steps:

1. Creates cart if it has not already existed
2. Stores this cart's id in session
3. Caches cart in instance variable `@current_cart`. It will also available in any view
4. Returns in cart's instance variable
5. saves this returning to `@cart` variable in show action for `carts_controller`

Comment: So there's no real reason for the `:id => current` bit in the route?

Comment: It is required to pass `:id` argument to show action according `REST`. So here  it is just fake parameter to get `REST` route and noting more. You can change this `id` to 'my_current_card' or `just_card` or another word and anything will work the same as now